Repairing steps with detached nosing
I have some indoor steps that are used very frequently and there's a piece of nosing is falling off. There were two small finish nails used (one is now detached).

Steps are made of a synthetic material
Underneath the nosing is a strip of wood (doesn't feel super solid -- almost like a long shim)
I can't tell what adhesive was used previously, I don't see any large visible smears or trails

Approach to fixing
My first thought is to try to pull the step off (somehow without damaging the wood) and then use construction adhesive to reattach it, but I am unsure of:

How to do this without damaging the nosing further
How to secure the nosing (it's at the very front of the step, so clamps are probably not going to work?)

I'm also very open to other options if there is something better out there :)
Pictures
Here is the broken step:

Here is a "good" step from the top:


Can you add a pic of the substrate where the veneer has come loose?

A thin wide nail puller should remove the nosing, if careful.
It looks like veneer and was probably put on with contact cement.
You will want to remove the old contact cement (do a web search) from both surfaces and apply new stuff.

Random image from search.
You might want one of the two on the left, or a claw hammer will work also.

In terms of replacement adhesive, would liquid nails be acceptable? Should I also nail the step again?

@NickTomlin  Liquid nails will work also.  The main thing is to have clean surfaces.  The nails mainly for holding it tight.
